# How do I add a utility sink drain into a tight space?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, washing-machine, laundry

I'm adding a laundry/utility tub to my garage and have exposed the existing plumbing behind the wall (see picture). I understand I need to have both the sink and washing machine drains vented, but I don't have a ton of space to work with. I can't really go beyond the studs on either side of the picture.

The plan is to have a stacked washer/dryer to the right, with the laundry sink on the left. I'd like to keep as much in the wall as possible, ideally with a laundry outlet box somewhere.

Is there a configuration (meeting CA code) that might work for this? A sketch would be helpful.

[image: Laundry plumbing small space]

Comment: You say that you are adding a "laundry/utility tub", so does that mean that you will be using the tub to drain the washing machine into, as is commonly done? In that case would you not just alter and use that existing washing-machine "standpipe" drain?

Comment: I'd like to avoid draining to the tub, though I realize that might be the most straightforward solution given the layout. Ideally two drains: sink + washing machine using a washer outlet box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning way too much about drains and venting, here’s how I solved adding a properly vented sink drain, plus a washer outlet. A professional plumber who was snaking the drain inspected it and gave it a thumbs up. Hope this is useful to anyone looking for ideas.
[image: Laundry and sink drain in tight stud bay]

Comment: Nice work. Did you also solder in the new hot/cold water cut offs and fittings?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did. Bought a torch and learned how to sweat copper — poorly. Had two small leaks I had to fix, but learned some things.